# I need to parse a php array and convert it to use with send in blue email provider

Tags: php, arrays, json

Send in Blue requires emails in the following format:

```
$emails = array("to_email@email.com"=>"to_name",...);
```

I have an array which is loaded from a database, which only has the email address separated by a comma. This array is actually quite large, so I need to loop through it and create another array.

```
$emailArray = array("x@x.com", "y@y.com", "z@z.com");
```

The replacement array would look something like the following:

```
$emails = array("x@x.com"=>"x@x.com", "y@y.com"=>"y@y.com", "z@z.com"=>"z@z.com");
```

Anyone any idea how I can do this?

Comment: [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) the array with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$emails = [];

foreach( $emailArray AS $email ) {
     $emails[$email] = $email;
}
```

If you now run `var_dump($emails)` you should have an array like you want it to be. What we are doing here is looping through every email, and setting the value of it as a key to the `$emails` array, and then setting its value to that given key

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone who is interested. I had to remind my self that what was required what was required was an associative array. A working solution is as follows:

```
// add outgoing addresses to email array
$emails = [];
$emailArray = array("x@x.com", "y@y.com", "z@z.com");
foreach ($emailArray as $email) {
    $emails[$email] = $email;
}
```

Comment: This is different from [Ole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850155/476) how…?